# Смена языка программно создаваемого JSF-меню

Tags: java-ee, jsf, primefaces

Имеется *JSF*-приложение, использующее *Primefaces*. Приложение должно поддерживать смену языка в любой момент работы. Для этого сделан комбо-бокс со списком языков, в котором пользователь выбирает нужный язык. При выборе вызывается обработчик, меняющий локаль следующим кодом:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(locale);
```

Всё работает прекрасно за исключением одной детали. Имеется меню, которое создаётся не в *XHTML*-файлах, а динамически, программно. В упрощённом виде это выглядит так:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MenuView implements Serializable {
    private MenuModel model;

    public MenuModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        model = new DefaultMenuModel();
        ResourceBundle messages =
            ResourceBundle.getBundle("i18n.messages",
                                     (Locale) getSession().getAttribute("locale"));

        DefaultSubMenu submenu = new DefaultSubMenu(messages.getString("Menu 1"));
        DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem(messages.getString("Item 1"));
        submenu.addElement(item);
        model.addElement(submenu);
    }
}
```

В *XHTML* присутствует такая строка:

```
<p:menu model="#{menuView.model}">
```

Так вот, это меню смену языка игнорирует и остаётся на том языке, который был в момент его создания, что, естественно, пользователю не понравится.

Каким образом перехватить событие смены локали и заставить меню отображаться на правильном языке? Можно его даже пересоздать, если необходимо.

---

Сейчас сделал следующим образом. При смене языка в комбо-боксе вызывается обработчик, который кроме смены локали вызывает также статический метод

```
MenuView.localeChanged();
```

Класс `MenuView` приобретает дополнительные поля и методы:

```
private MenuView instance;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    // ...
    instance = this;
}

public static void localeChanged() {
    if (instance != null)
        instance.init();
}
```

Но данный подход мне не нравится, потому что класс, управляющий локалью, приобретает совершенно ненужное ему знание о классах меню, т.е. возникает лишняя зависимость классов.

Нельзя ли как-то обойтись без этой зависимости?

Comment: Была похожая проблема: решал тем, что при смене языка заставлял пользователя заново логиниться в систему, чтобы сбросить сессию и пересоздавать sessionscoped бины. Либо можно изменить `SessionScoped` на `ViewScoped` для бина меню. Но тоже не самые лучшие решения.

Comment: @PavelParshin Повторный логин - не вариант, явно противоречит ТЗ. Смена языка должна выполняться без перелогинивания. А `@ViewScoped` пробовал - не пересоздаётся.

Comment: @PavelParshin Хм... Я немного дурак. Не тот импорт поставил. Взял `javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped`, а надо было `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped`. Стало пересоздаваться. Но теперь пересоздаётся при каждом чихе, что тоже не есть хорошо.

Comment: Вот поэтому и написал, что не лучшее решение. Как вариант, искать все `SessionScoped` бины и пересоздавать их при смене языка. Потому что, возможно, не только меню будет кешироваться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если гора не идёт к Магомету, то Магомет идёт к горе. Иными словами, если фреймворк не генерирует событие о смене локали, то мы его сгенерируем сами. Получилось следующее.

Класс события смены локали:

```
public class LocaleChanged
{
}
```

Класс, обрабатывающий событие смены локали:

```
import javax.enterprise.event.Event;

@javax.inject.Named
@javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped
public class LocaleBean implements Serializable
{
    @javax.inject.Inject
    private Event<LocaleChanged> localeChangedEvent;

    public void localeChanged(final ValueChangeEvent event) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(event.getNewValue().toString()));
        localeChangedEvent.fire(new LocaleChanged());
    }
}
```

Класс `MenuView`, обрабатывающий событие смены локали:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.event.Observes;

@javax.inject.Named
@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean
@javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped
@javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped
public class MenuView implements Serializable {
    private MenuModel model;

    public MenuModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        model = new DefaultMenuModel();
        ResourceBundle messages =
            ResourceBundle.getBundle("i18n.messages",
                                     (Locale) getSession().getAttribute("locale"));

        DefaultSubMenu submenu = new DefaultSubMenu(messages.getString("Menu 1"));
        DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem(messages.getString("Item 1"));
        submenu.addElement(item);
        model.addElement(submenu);
    }

    private void onLocaleChanged(@Observes final LocaleChanged localeChanged)
    {
        init();
    }
}
```

При смене языка меню просто пересоздаётся.

Следует обратить внимание список аннтоаций класса `MenuView`. Поскольку используется "смешанная" технология (*JSF* + *CDI*), необходимо помечать бин как сессионный двумя аннотациями - `@javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped` для *CDI* и `@javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped` для *JSF*. В противном случае бин будет создаваться заново.

Достоинство данного подхода в том, что бин, меняющий локаль теряет "знание" об объектах, которым необходимо меняться при смене локали. Объект просто "подписывается" на это событие. Тем самым достигается слабая связность.

Answer (score 0):

Преждевременная оптимизация многих уже подводила. Вы кешируете состояние меню (создавая единожды за всю сессию) ещё до того, как добились его стопроцентной функциональности, а это одна из самых главных проблем преждевременной оптимизации. Смените уровень видимости контроллера на `@RequestScoped`, удалите метод `init` вместе с аннотацией `@PostConstruct` а его содержимое перенесите в `getModel()`. Пусть при каждом обращении оно будет формироваться "с нуля", зато с использованием актуальной локали.

PS Потом, когда ваше приложение "загнётся" от нагрузки (если оно доживёт до такой популярности) и вы всё-таки проведёте нагрузочное тестирование и анализ "узких" мест, то станет понятно, что кеширование этой части - далеко не самая приоритетная из задач.

Comment: Посчитайте ради интереса сколько раз вызывается `getModel` при генерации ***одной*** страницы.

Comment: Не имеет значения сколько раз, до тех пор пока не произведены замеры производительности и затрат ресурсов. Добавьте код, подсчитывающий время всех вызовов метода, и сравните это время с временем открытия страницы. Если окажется, что метод "съедает" более одной десятой доли процента - то я не прав